# Regex - Find between two strings not having third string

Tags: regex

I have this string:

> `It starts with "a man is walking in the" plus "he smiles";`

I want to get all words starting with `"` ending with `";` which will return `"he smiles"`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
"([^"]+?)";
```

The Group1 will contain `"he smiles"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

words starting with ":

```
/^"(.+)\s/
```

words ending with ":

```
/\s(.+)"$/
```

Note: Leave the `^` or `$` off if its not at the end/beginning of the string you want the match.